# Using across function in dplyr to a subset of variables

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I have a data frame like this:

```
require(dplyr)

x_1=rnorm(10,0,1)
x_2=rnorm(10,0,1)
x_3=rnorm(10,0,1)
y_1=rnorm(10,0,1)
y_2=rnorm(10,0,1)

data=data.frame(cbind(x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2))
data[1,1]=NA
data[2,1]=NA
data[5,2]=NA

> data
          x_1        x_2         x_3        y_1        y_2
1          NA  0.9272000  0.29439845 -1.7856567  1.6579091
2          NA  0.2346621  1.09837343  0.3731092  0.6111779
3   0.7315300 -0.5579094 -0.08524311 -2.8661310  1.1545358
4  -0.9469221  0.6929277 -2.67173898  0.6391045 -0.5114099
5   1.5408777         NA  1.33386146 -0.5581233 -2.5733381
6  -0.2852210 -0.9532492  0.03750860 -1.0129503  0.3929722
7  -1.3821487 -2.1865094 -0.03039062  0.3960388 -1.5332137
8  -0.9447420  0.2669902  0.65167163  0.4310705 -1.5300816
9  -0.9023479  0.2068130  0.10868635 -1.1652238 -0.4892178
10 -0.9739177 -0.8094084  0.64103491  0.6063812  0.7248394
```

I need to create a new variable which counts the number of non missing values in each row for the variables starting with  "x_". To do that I used `mutate` and `across` functions from `dplyr`.

```
data=data %>% mutate(sum_no_miss=across(.cols = starts_with("x_"),~ sum(is.na(.x))))
```

I ran the code without getting error. But I am not getting the ourput that I want. I am getting this.
[image]

Would it be possible to tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, `data.frame(cbind(...))` is an anti-pattern. `cbind()` creates a matrix, which will convert everything to one class potentially causing problems. You're better off using `data.frame` directly without the `cbind()`: `data = data.frame(x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2)` is less typing, more efficient, and safer.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you for your suggestion. I did like that initially. But using wrong syntax. (data = data.frame(c(x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2))) and got wrong results. That's why I used cbind. Now I understood my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `rowSums` which is vectorized and efficient compared to `rowwise` with `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   mutate(sum_no_miss = rowSums(!is.na(across(starts_with("x_")))))
```

-output

```
          x_1        x_2         x_3        y_1        y_2 sum_no_miss
1          NA  0.9272000  0.29439845 -1.7856567  1.6579091           2
2          NA  0.2346621  1.09837343  0.3731092  0.6111779           2
3   0.7315300 -0.5579094 -0.08524311 -2.8661310  1.1545358           3
4  -0.9469221  0.6929277 -2.67173898  0.6391045 -0.5114099           3
5   1.5408777         NA  1.33386146 -0.5581233 -2.5733381           2
6  -0.2852210 -0.9532492  0.03750860 -1.0129503  0.3929722           3
7  -1.3821487 -2.1865094 -0.03039062  0.3960388 -1.5332137           3
8  -0.9447420  0.2669902  0.65167163  0.4310705 -1.5300816           3
9  -0.9023479  0.2068130  0.10868635 -1.1652238 -0.4892178           3
10 -0.9739177 -0.8094084  0.64103491  0.6063812  0.7248394           3
```

---

If we want to use `sum`, then need `rowwise`

```
data %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(sum_no_miss = sum(!is.na(c_across(starts_with('x_'))))) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 6
      x_1    x_2     x_3    y_1    y_2 sum_no_miss
    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>       <int>
 1 NA      0.927  0.294  -1.79   1.66            2
 2 NA      0.235  1.10    0.373  0.611           2
 3  0.732 -0.558 -0.0852 -2.87   1.15            3
 4 -0.947  0.693 -2.67    0.639 -0.511           3
 5  1.54  NA      1.33   -0.558 -2.57            2
 6 -0.285 -0.953  0.0375 -1.01   0.393           3
 7 -1.38  -2.19  -0.0304  0.396 -1.53            3
 8 -0.945  0.267  0.652   0.431 -1.53            3
 9 -0.902  0.207  0.109  -1.17  -0.489           3
10 -0.974 -0.809  0.641   0.606  0.725           3
```

---

In the OP's code, the function `sum` is used within `across` and `across` loops over each column, thus the `sum` will be the sum of non-NA elements in each column instead of across a row

Answer (score 3):

First, you're close.

Edit: OP fixed this I believe, so not a relevant comment. Second, your variables are coded in a misleading way - you should rename your variable `sum_is_miss` to something like `sum_no_miss` if you want readers to understand that you're calculating the number of non-missing values.

Third, this is how you could calculate the number of non-missing entries per row in your dataset first using apply then just adding this column to your dataset:

```r
library(tidyverse)

x_1=rnorm(10,0,1)
x_2=rnorm(10,0,1)
x_3=rnorm(10,0,1)
y_1=rnorm(10,0,1)
y_2=rnorm(10,0,1)

data=data.frame(cbind(x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2))
data[1,1]=NA
data[2,1]=NA
data[5,2]=NA


sum_no_miss_vec <- apply(data %>% dplyr::select(starts_with("x_")), MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(r){
  sum(!is.na(r))
})
data2 <- data %>% mutate(sum_no_miss = sum_no_miss_vec) ;
data2
#>           x_1         x_2         x_3          y_1         y_2 sum_no_miss
#> 1          NA  0.74234418  1.06515091 -0.313359946 -0.81266805           2
#> 2          NA  2.13222122  0.78392737  2.109171065  0.69459821           2
#> 3   0.9322299 -0.52545325  0.67377319  2.025281430  0.99975832           3
#> 4   0.9634517  0.38985353  1.20940016 -0.007232240 -1.61104902           3
#> 5   0.4454230          NA  0.02420848 -1.743636503 -0.59597234           2
#> 6  -1.7305822  2.07163152 -0.52849895  0.830802138 -1.40573549           3
#> 7   0.2382603  0.20427098  0.22184048  0.806113977 -0.36726054           3
#> 8  -0.3972436  1.61183785 -0.26835072  0.419459671 -0.05723072           3
#> 9   0.3703195 -0.05354607 -1.19558014 -0.852003930  0.64032424           3
#> 10  0.3003434 -0.82513981  0.19782771  0.001526784  0.89393655           3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a base R solution:**

As akrun already provided the best answer. Here is a different one using base R:

We use `apply` with `grep` to apply the function to specific columns:

```
data$sum_no_miss <- apply(data[, grep("x_", names(data))], 1, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))
```

```
          x_1        x_2         x_3        y_1        y_2 sum_no_miss
1          NA -0.5659449 -1.44792814  0.1659370  0.8040186           2
2          NA  2.6873635 -0.70704189  1.2647756 -0.1238085           2
3  -0.3239291  0.6206436  0.04374401 -0.6476829  1.5228775           3
4   0.7245148  1.6632621 -0.39304104 -0.9305281  1.1328385           3
5  -0.5994830         NA  0.06037891 -1.7654617  0.3073035           2
6  -0.1848746  0.3694963 -1.13622715  0.9252195  0.1072250           3
7  -0.1147132  0.4042102  1.56730477  0.3262673 -0.6369951           3
8  -0.8631230  0.2888508 -2.20030009 -0.9873629  0.2561348           3
9  -0.9384460 -0.8739620 -1.59174131  0.7559146 -1.4229472           3
10 -0.9352575  1.3151532 -0.11439843 -0.5451860  0.9334084           3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible `data.table` solution, using `Reduce` and `lapply` on the specific columns using `grep`.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(data)

dt[, num_obs := Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, \(x) !is.na(x))), .SDcols=grep("x_", names(dt))]
```

**Output**

```
           x_1         x_2          x_3         y_1        y_2 sum_no_miss
 1:          NA  1.30228879 -0.586898083 -1.02679871 -0.9280488           2
 2:          NA -1.00846632 -0.260183508 -0.78828113 -0.8712957           2
 3: -0.40475601  0.22961832  0.004414558 -1.04496673 -0.1032775           3
 4:  0.09559518 -0.58875533  1.360528488 -0.48798151 -0.6350380           3
 5: -0.39312997          NA  0.292025300  1.13544025 -0.2487097           2
 6: -1.15802973  1.01589098  0.445829196 -0.02029337  0.9758154           3
 7: -0.02524740 -0.17334510 -1.455821490 -0.12165396 -0.4441740           3
 8:  0.93627901 -0.92913166  0.407038460  2.04054914 -0.8347571           3
 9:  1.20218530  0.54453181  0.513222262  0.05571475 -0.4858128           3
10:  0.84765702  0.07472934  1.367745731 -1.49924113 -1.3170490           3
```